# Sublime Text 2 - Find and Replace: "case-sensitive" vs "preserve case"?

Tags: sublimetext2

In the Find/Replace dialog, what is the difference between the options "case-sensitive" and "preserve case"?

Comment: Is there a way of enabling this "preserve-case" feature to CMD-D replace function?

Comment: you can switch between case-sensitive-insensitive search mode by pressing `cmd+alt+c` (or `alt+c`)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The **Case sensitive** option determines what will be matched. The **Preserve case** option determines if the matched text's case is preserved or not when replacing it with the replacement string.

Here's an example which should make this clear. Imagine you have this:

```
word
Word
```

If **Case sensitive** is not selected and you look for `word`, text from both lines will be selected. If it is selected, only the first, lowercase `word` will be matched.

Let's say we're using `tapioca` as the replacement string. If **Preserve case** is not selected (and **Case sensitive** isn't either), a Replace All would give you the following result:

```
tapioca
tapioca
```

With **Preserve case** enabled, it would instead become:

```
tapioca
Tapioca
```

i.e., the second `Word`'s case would be preserved and "applied" to the replacement string.

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger This option appears in the "Replace…" dialog (present under the "Find" menu; it can also be invoked using Cmd+Option+F under OSX). In that dialog, the "Preserve case" option can be switched on/off using the lower left button (which looks like two superimposed squares).

Comment: I must not have the same version, I really can't find this option. Anyway, I went for two replaces case sensitive : prevVarname -> nextVarname and PrevClassname -> NextClassname instead of replacing prev by next preserve case, which is more touchy! But thanks !